# Powershell Studio getting AD Description from IP

Tags: powershell, scripting

The goal of this code is as follows

- Create a searchable text box (w/ button) that allows me to display the following in a RichTextBox (whether IP or Hostname is entered):
- Description
- Hostname
- IP
- Operating System

Everything works great, except I'd like to be able to type in any IP Address and grab the 'description' from Active Directory. Currently I am using `GetHostByName`

```
foreach ($item in ([system.Net.dns]::GetHostByName($preSearchComputer)).AddressList.ipaddresstostring)
{
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $item -Count 1 -Quiet)
    {
        $Computer = ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($item)).HostName
        $system = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName "$Computer" | Select-Object -property name
        $networkResult = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -Filter 'ipenabled = "true"' -ComputerName $Computer
        $os = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer
        $description = Get-ADComputer -Filter ('Name -like "*' + $($Computer.Split("."))[0] + '*"') -Property description

        $Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            'Name'        = $system.Name
            'IP Address'  = $networkResult.IPAddress
            'OS Caption'  = $os.Caption
            'Description' = $description.description
```

which will convert a single IP to a hostname which is inconvenient and I know that it has been deprecated for some time.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please do not post code on external sites where it may vanish at any given point in time, rendering your question useless to everyone else. Everything that is relevant for your question should be *in your question*.

Comment: You are using WMI to get the hostname, which my guess would be (Didn't look that closely) the FWDN of the remote host, myComputer.domain.com... So look that up or the hostname in AD (I like QAD tools for this)

Comment: Emphasizing what @AnsgarWiechers said: When your pastebin link expires, this question will be much less useful to others. Include the relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hello LazyPowershellScripter, You could just filter your Get-ADComputer on the IPv4Address attribute. Hope this helps. Cheers, Chris
`$description = (Get-ADComputer -Filter {IPv4Address -eq $item} -Property description).description`

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately that means I still have to pass through $presearchcomputer which is a singular IP or hostname.